# Solution for the trignometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking for a solution for an equation of the form :
$ax - \sin(bx) + c = 0$. Without the constant term $c$, I can easily take a derivative to get the solution. But how do I take into account the constant?

[This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20sin%20x%20%2B%20x%20-10%20%3D%200) gives me the answer, but how do I find the solution?

Comment: Numerically. If you need exact solution, google Kepler equation (for $a=b$)

Comment: In my case, a is not equal to b. But it's cool to know my equation is so close to orbital mechanics! :)

Comment: If $c=0$, then obviously one solution is $x=0$.  But there are other solutions if $0<a<b$ and you say you can easily take a derivative to get a solution.  How do you do that? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If c = 0, derivative is of the form `a - b * cos(b * x) = 0`. I can take cos inverse to find x.

Comment: Derivative is of that form for any $c$, not just $c=0$. Anyway that will give you possible maxima, minima and inflection points, **not** the zeros of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you face equations which mix polynomial and trigonometric terms, you cannot expect any analytical solution (remember that there is no closed form solution to the equation $x=\cos(x)$) and only numerical methods can be used for getting the solution.

Considering the equation 
$$f(x)=ax - \sin(bx) + c $$ yo can notice that it is bounded by $ax+(c-1)$ and $ax+(c+1)$ and then the solution is somewhere between $x_1=-\frac {c-1}a$ and $x_2=-\frac {c+1}a$ which means that $x_0=-\frac {c}a$ (as Lucian wrote) is probably a good starting point for Newton method. The iterates will then be given by $$x_{n+1}=\frac{b\, x_n \cos (b x_n)-\sin (b x_n)+c}{b \cos (b x_n)-a}$$

But we can generate a better estimate computing $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$, establishing the equation of the straight line joining these points and, from there, computing the $x$ intercept. This will give $$x_0=\frac{c-c \sin \left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \cos \left(\frac{b
   c}{a}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \sin \left(\frac{b
   c}{a}\right)}{a \left(\sin \left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \cos \left(\frac{b
   c}{a}\right)-1\right)}$$

You should notice that the example you added to the post leads to an approximate solution $x\approx 11.0000$ just because $11 \approx 3.50141 \pi$  which makes $$\sin(11)\approx \sin(3.50141 \pi)=-\sin(0.50141 \pi)=-\sin(\frac \pi 2+0.00141\pi)=-\cos(0.00141\pi)$$ which is $\approx -0.99999$. If you apply Newton method to this case ($a=1,b=-1,c=-10$),   the successive iterates will be $$x_0=10.999966682789284969$$ $$x_1=10.999990249931731937$$ $$x_2=10.999990249655250451$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but why don't the values from RHS to LHS match with each other? `sin(11)≈sin(3.50141π)=−sin(0.50141π)=−sin(π2+0.00141π)=−cos(0.00141π)`

Comment: $\sin(11) \approx -0.999990206551$ and $-\cos \left(\frac{141 \pi }{100000}\right)  \approx -0.999990189136$

Comment: worked for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an analytic solution? You can approximate it with  [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), for example.

Comment: I recommend an initial value of $x_0=\frac{c}{b-a}$.

Comment: x0 = 0.005 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

That is a [trascendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) equation. In general, you can only solve it using [numerical methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis). You can find an [analytic solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) for some specific cases, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read about this before getting back

Answer (score 0):

> $x=-\dfrac ca+\dfrac1a\cdot\sin\bigg(-\dfrac{bc}a+\dfrac ba\cdot\sin\bigg(-\dfrac{bc}a+\dfrac ba\cdot\sin\bigg(-\dfrac{bc}a+\dfrac ba\cdot\sin\bigg(\cdots\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)$